# How to use sql data in django without any templete tag such as for is i only have a single data

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am building a portfolio and i am just learning django i tried to bring data from About in sql and since i have only single piece of data i dont need for loop so i tried putting it directly but is seems i cannot do that. Any suggestion on how i can do it

```html
 <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="about-large d-none d-lg-block text-uppercase">About</div>
      <div class="about-me row mt-5">
        <div class="my-image col-md-5">
          <img src="{{ about.image }}" />
        </div>
        <div class="my-description col-md-6">
          <h3>About Me</h3>
          <h4>I am {{about.name}}</h4>
          <p>{{ about.description }}</p>
          <p>{{ about.description_two }}</p>
          <div class="cv-hire d-flex flex-start">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark font-weight-bold">
              <a href="{{ about.cv }}">Download <i class="fas fa-download pl-2"></i></a>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

[image: my data in sqllite]

My Views .py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import *


class HomeTemplateView(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'home.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['about'] = About.objects.first()
    context['services'] = Service.objects.all()
    context['works'] = RecentWork.objects.all()
    return context
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

class About(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/img")
name = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="My Name")
description = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Description")
description_two = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Description", blank=True)
cv = models.FileField(upload_to="static/document")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "About Me"
    verbose_name_plural = "About Me"

def __str__(self):
    return "About Me"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make some checks:

- What returns About.objects.first() in Django shell?
- Make template with {{ about.cv }} only to avoid other influences.

Then I can see if expected data exist and what incomes to template.

Comment: "GET /static/document/cv.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 22  and for the second one 5ArYvPCqwi9JkPu7ZlirOg

Comment: I used ImageField where Picture.objects.first() returns <ImageFieldFile: /path> and Picture.objects.first().picture.path returns absolute filesystem path to file. So I recommend add .path to your variable in the template about.cv.path. Or about.cv.name should return relative path. Or about.cv.url should return absolute path to your media root.

Comment: it worked thanks but can i ask a question why it does not work when i use objects.all() but work if i use objects.first()

Comment: .all returns list of objects, .first returns single object. So with .all you should use index: .all()[0] for example. Then you can write .all()[0].cv.path.